# How to change placeholder after user guesses/inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, placeholder

I'm making a game about trying to guess the driver depending on the teams he has drived for. I want the user to see how many guesses he has and how many he has guessed. For example if the driver has drived for 3 teams the user could only guess 3 times and then when the user is guessing first the placeholder should be 'Guess 1 of 3', if the user guesses correct the game ends and it should show all the drivers career. But if the user guesses wrong then the next placeholder should be 'Guess 2 of 3' and so on.
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="guess_driver_path.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

<head>
    <title>formula1.pro</title>
    <style>
            .home {
      color: white; /* Change the color to black */
      text-decoration: none; /* Remove the underline */
    }
        body {
           /* background-image: url("background.png"); */
           background-color: #adadad;
        }

        .container {
            margin: 50px auto;
            max-width: 800px;
            padding: 100px;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        .career {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        label {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .guess[type="text"], textarea {
            width: 100%;
            padding:15px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            resize: none;
        }

        .guess {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .guess {
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        #guess_count {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        header h1 {
        margin: 0;
    }

    header button {
        background-color: white;
        color: #000;
        border: none;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    header button:hover {
        background-color: #f5f5f5
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>
              <a style="justify-content: left; font-size: 2em;" class="home" href="index.html">
              &nbsp;  &nbsp; Formula1
              </a>
            </h1>
            <div class="menu">
              <div class="nav-menu">
              <a href="higher_or_lower.html" class="menu-link">Higher or Lower</a>
              <a href="guess_driver_path.html" class="menu-link">Guess Drivers Path</a>
              <a href="rankings.html" class="menu-link">Standings</a>
              <a href="chat.html" class="menu-link">Chat</a>
              </div>
              <img src="rotate.png" class="car" />
              <div class="follow">
            &equiv;
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">Guess the driver's career</h1>
        <form id="guess_driver_path">
            <div class="h3">Drivers Career:</div>
            <div class="career">
            </div>
            <div class="gues">
                <label style="font-size: 2em;" for="guess">Guess the driver:</label>
                <textarea id="guess" placeholder="Guess x of x" name="guess" rows="1" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
        <script src="guess_driver_path.js"></script>
        <div class="contact">
            <h1><a id="contact" href="mailto:@gmail.com">Contact</a></h1>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <h1><a id="privacy" href="...">Privacy</a></h1>
          </div>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
// Define the list of drivers with their respective career paths
const drivers = [
    {
      name: "Sebastian Vettel",
      aliases: ["sebastian","vettel"],
      career: [
        { team: "Red Bull", years: "2009-2014" },
        { team: "Ferrari", years: "2015-2020" },
        { team: "Aston Martin", years: "2021-2022" }
      ],
      maxGuesses: 3
    },
    {
      name: "Lewis Hamilton",
      aliases: ["lewis","hamilton"],
      career: [
        { team: "McLaren", years: "2007-2012" },
        { team: "Mercedes", years: "2013-" }
      ],
      maxGuesses: 2
    },
    {
      name: "Max Verstappen",
      aliases: ["max","verstappen"],
      career: [
        { team: "Toro Rosso", years: "2015" },
        { team: "Red Bull", years: "2016-" }
      ],
      maxGuesses: 2
    },
    {
        name: "Michael Schumacher",
        aliases: ["michael","schumacher"],
        career: [
          { team: "Jordan", years: "1991" },
          { team: "Benetton", years: "1991-1995" },
          { team: "Ferrari", years: "1996-2006" },
          { team: "Mercedes", years: "2010-2012" }
        ],
        maxGuesses: 4
    },
    // Add more drivers here
  ];
  
// Get the elements from the HTML document
const form = document.querySelector("#guess_driver_path");
const guessInput = form.querySelector("#guess");
const careerDiv = document.querySelector(".career");
const textArea = document.querySelector("#guess");



// Generate a random driver for the user to guess
let currentDriverIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * drivers.length);
let currentDriver = drivers[currentDriverIndex];
let currentTeamIndex = 0;

// Display the first team for the current driver
careerDiv.innerHTML += `<div>${currentDriver.career[currentTeamIndex].team} ${currentDriver.career[currentTeamIndex].years}</div>`;

// Handle the form submission
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const guess = guessInput.value.trim();
  guessInput.value = "";

  // Check if the guess matches the current driver
  if (guess.toLowerCase() === currentDriver.name.toLowerCase()) {
    alert(`That's correct! The driver is ${currentDriver.name}`);
    // Generate a new random driver for the user to guess
    currentDriverIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * drivers.length);
    currentDriver = drivers[currentDriverIndex];
    currentTeamIndex = 0;
    careerDiv.innerHTML = ""; // Clear the contents of the careerDiv element
    careerDiv.innerHTML += `<div>${currentDriver.career[currentTeamIndex].team} ${currentDriver.career[currentTeamIndex].years}</div>`;
  } else {
    alert(`Sorry, that's not correct. Keep guessing!`);
    // Display the next team for the current driver, if there is one
    if (currentTeamIndex < currentDriver.career.length - 1) {
      currentTeamIndex++;
      careerDiv.innerHTML += `<div>${currentDriver.career[currentTeamIndex].team} ${currentDriver.career[currentTeamIndex].years}</div>`;
    }
  }
});

guessInput.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    form.dispatchEvent(new Event("submit"));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two variables were added to the second list of variables: `guessMax`, which is determined by the number of cars the driver has, and `guessesNumber`, which represents the current guess number and is initialized to 1 before any guesses are made.

It is recommended to correct this in the HTML by either writing 1 instead of x, or by completely removing the caption from the HTML and letting JS write it.

Additionally, an `UpdatedSeveralGuesses()` function was added to update the guess number, and it is triggered on the first run of the script and every time a guess is entered.

This is how the (relevant part of the) code looks now:

```
let currentDriverIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * drivers.length);
let currentDriver = drivers[currentDriverIndex];
let currentTeamIndex = 0;
//The number of possible guesses based on the number of driver careers
let guessesMax = currentDriver.career.length;
let guessesNumber = 1;
// a function that updates the guess number.
function UpdatedSveralGuesses(){
guessInput.placeholder = `Guess ${guessesNumber} of ${guessesMax}`;
}

// Display the first team for the current driver
careerDiv.innerHTML += `<div>${currentDriver.career[currentTeamIndex].team} ${currentDriver.career[currentTeamIndex].years}</div>`;

UpdatedSveralGuesses();

// Handle the form submission
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const guess = guessInput.value.trim();
  guessInput.value = "";

  // Check if the guess matches the current driver
  if (guess.toLowerCase() === currentDriver.name.toLowerCase()) {
    alert(`That's correct! The driver is ${currentDriver.name}`);
    // Generate a new random driver for the user to guess
    currentDriverIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * drivers.length);
    currentDriver = drivers[currentDriverIndex];
    currentTeamIndex = 0;
    careerDiv.innerHTML = ""; // Clear the contents of the careerDiv element
    careerDiv.innerHTML += `<div>${currentDriver.career[currentTeamIndex].team} ${currentDriver.career[currentTeamIndex].years}</div>`;
  } else {
    alert(`Sorry, that's not correct. Keep guessing!`);
       //Update the number of guesses
            guessesNumber++;
            UpdatedSveralGuesses();
    // Display the next team for the current driver, if there is one
    //From here on I did not change the code
```

Note that you need to improve a few more things in your code. First, you must ensure that the user cannot continue to guess after he passes the maximum number of guesses.

Second, you need to add a message to the user that will be displayed when they exceed the maximum.

To make it convenient for you to work, arrange the code in a good way. For example, you write twice the commands for loading a new driver and hints about the driver (`careerDiv.innerHTML`....), which will make it difficult to handle the code. Put these commands into a function that you can handle centrally, and call the function wherever you need it.